# How to pass a server side property value to other htm page loaded in frame withing aspx page

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html, web

In a web application, I have a default.aspx page and have a button at top and shown below:
[image]

When I click the Button-1, a frame is loaded in my page containing two other frames in a frameset. Each frame in frameset loads a htm page.
You can see this as below:
[image]

So, hierarchy is as below:

1. Loaded Default.aspx Page
2. Click on Button-1
3. A Frame is loaded in body of default.aspx which hides the previous contents and display newly loaded frame contents.
4. Newly loaded frame contains a frameset in Default.htm page
5. Loaded frameset have two frames, first load Header.htm and second loads Contents.htm

What I need to do, I want to set the value of Button-2 in Header.htm and that value is assigned to a javascript variable on Default.aspx load.

I try this  `var sJSButton2Value = '<%=sButton2Title %>';`
sButton2Title comes from server side script depending upon user language.

How, can I pass this to Header.htm from Default.aspx ?
I want to set Button-2 value which is coming from Default.aspx page.
How It can be accomplished ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the variable in Default.aspx from an iframe like this:

From inside the iframe:

```
window.parent.SomeFunctionDefinedInDefaultAspx(valueToSet);
```

This is typically how you would access the "parent" (Default.aspx) of the iframe

f you need the button text to be set in the iframe from Default.aspx, you can do that via querystring in the url your specify for the iframe